# Why am I getting a black screen between legacy Bios Bootscreen and Linux/Windows installation screen?

Tags: boot, installation, bios

My Hardware:

- MSI X58 E-Pro Mainboard with 1366 Socket (release in 2009 —> only legacy bios)
- Xeon E 5620 (release early 2010)
- 6x 2GB RAM
- 300W Power Supply
- intel boxed cooler
- AMD Radeon RX 5700

What I want to achieve:

I want to set up a home server for personal usage like a cloud storage and a mail server.

How I planed to achieve that / Context:

In 2018 I built myself my first PC. I used old Hardware because it was cheap. Then exactly two years ago I wanted an upgrade and bought myself a new intel processor, got a new motherboard from my parents and sold my Nvidia GPU and switched to Radeon (RX 5700) because I found interest in building a Hackintosh (Nvidia is not supported for new generation macOS).

In the last couple of weeks/months I started to think about using my old hardware to built a homeserver.

I bought myself a new power supply (only 300W because I didn’t want to spend much money for this experimental project) and a new cooler (I use my 500W power supply and my bequiet! Cooler for my „new“ PC). I plan to access my server only via terminal within the Termius iPad App winch is why I don‘t need a GPU. I only need one for the installation for what I‘d like to use my Radeon.

My progress so far:

At first I tested if the system works by accessing the Bios. That was fine. Then I created a bootable Ubuntu desktop USB Type-A Stick (3.1) with Rufus (MasterBootRecord) and plugged it into the Mainboard. I unplugged my GPU from my main system and plugged it into my future homeserver.

I set the boot queue correctly but after the bios screen there is only black.

Then I tried to reduce the sources of errors by:

- using my 500W power supply, nothing.
- I reset the bios and cmos, nothing.
- I switched Ram sticks and booted with only 4GB (2 sticks), nothing.
- I thought of my USB stick being the problem (my system booted perfectly from it though). So I used balenaEtcher and did some formatting in macOS to be sure the USB Stick is 100% in MBR.
- I tried to upgrade my bios via Rufus dos bootable or something and via the bios integrated option. But still nothing.
- I remembered that Windows 10 worked perfectly in 2018 so I tried to install Win10 with the USB Stick, nothing.
- I even plugged my GPU into a different PCI-e slot because the one I used before my have been damaged when I switched systems.
- I used different kinds of usb sticks, different monitors, that were and are still working.

To sum up, I did a lot of research and could exclude MANY potential reasons for the blackscreen.

How can I find this mysterious error of booting 4 years ago but not today.

Comment: help? I'd like some help on this. Could this be the wrong forum to ask this question?

Comment: So, I inserted an old GPU from a friend. A 1060. The RX 5700 is supposedly too new. I had to connect it via HDMI, then it worked.